# why the word[label+num] changes the eax?

Tags: assembly, nasm

```
section .data
fun:
   add word[L+2],0x203
L: mov eax,0x1020304 ; this instruction including operand stored in 5 byte in memory
   ret
```

what the "fun" function do? why eax will have a new value 0x1040604

Comment: What is code doing in `.data` section?

Comment: not given, just this... the question is what the fun return (the return value is in eax)

Comment: No I don't get it. It shouldn't have changed the value. The 0203 should be written exactly to the 0203 in the constant that's already there. And in any case, 0x1040604 would be impossible - where do 04 and 06 come from? They're nowhere to be seen.

Comment: i think because in the L there is 5 bytes in the memory, so have to add word[L+2] which is 2 bytes to 203.... but what is [L+2] exactly? so the 2+2 and 3+3 is the 4 and 6 but i dont understand it

Comment: and i think that assuemed that the function return in eax value, so i think that the answer should be before the line mov eax 1020304.... but i get 2030 + 203 which is  4033 not 4060

Comment: @aseed ok, facepalm for me, I should not be on here before my first coffee ;)
So it's an add instead of a mov, how the heck did I not notice that. Well that explains it. Anyway, posting answer now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you have a `mov eax, 0x1020304`, with a 5-byte encoding (there is a 6-byte encoding as well, but let's ignore that). So it looks like this (remember - little endian):

```
B8 04 03 02 01
```

Where L refers to the B8 and L+2 refers to the 03. Now if you add 0x0203 to it (remember - little endian), the 03 is added to the 03 and the 02 is added to the 02, so you get this:

```
B8 04 06 04 01
```

Which is:

```
mov eax, 0x01040604
```

Comment: but in little indian i have a stack include [40,30,20,10] not [04,03,02,01] ..?

Comment: @aseed no.. where does that zero at the end come from?

Comment: [04,30,20,10] why you reverse the numbers

Comment: You cannot push half of a byte to the stack. 0x1 is the same as 0x01

Comment: @aseed not really. That constant is missing the initial zero. If you count carefully you see it's only 7 hex chars. The extra zero is at the beginning not at the end (which would change the value).

Comment: @aseed: +1 for little "indian"